# При нажимании на кнопку "Купить" хочу, что бы PYбот подключался к БД считывал определенную информацию, заносил в словарь, и создавал кнопки с ключами

Tags: база-данных, python-telegram-bot

По задумке бот должен считать данные из базы (продукты) и добавлять их в кнопки под сообщением. Дальше уже при нажатии на соответствующий продукт будут показаны все его цены. По сути я сделал что-то подходящее, только есть одна загвоздка: при повторном вызове этой функции бот повторно создает блок имеющихся кнопок (фото ниже). Вот сижу и думаю, как это сделать по-человечески, а то у меня реализация какая-то обезьянья XD буду рад помощи
Ниже прилагаю кусок кода

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'buy')
def buying(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot_table.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table_1')
    kultura_table = cur.fetchall()
    for el in kultura_table:
        if el[1] not in kulura_dic:
            kulura_dic[el[1]] = el[2]
        elif el[1] in kulura_dic:
            kulura_dic[el[1]] += el[2]

    for key in kulura_dic.keys():
        btn_test1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"{key}", callback_data='button')
        market_buttons.row(btn_test1)

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ознакомьтесь', reply_markup=market_buttons)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрел до самого низа, фото не увидел.

Comment: Я забыл добавить ._.

Comment: Вроде теперь видно

Comment: Так у тебя функция каждый раз добавляет кнопки. Добавь в начало функции удаление всех кнопок, тогда после функции они будут по одному разу.

Comment: Пытаюсь это сделать со помощью данной команды: bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id + 1)
Но он не может удалить кнопки у еще неотправленного сообщения